# Connect networks to services

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have just 2 days of learning docker, and I don't know how to find on how to connect two services. So in my case, I'm in an exercise that I need to

- poll-tier to allow poll to communicate with redis.
- result-tier to allow result to communicate with db.
- back-tier to allow worker to communicate with redis and db.

and my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    poll:
        build: poll/.
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        networks: 
            - poll-tier
    redis:
        image: "redis"
        expose: 
            - "6379"
    worker:
        build: worker/.
        networks: 
            - back-tier
    db:
        image: "postgres"
        volumes:
            - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"        
    result:
        build: result/.
        networks: 
            - result-tier
volumes:
    db-data:
networks:
    poll-tier:
        name: redis
    result-tier:
        name: db
    back-tier:
        name: redis, db
```

So the question is, how I am able to communicate with the different services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By adding a network to a service you are limiting it to communicate within that network only, so in your case for cross communication you need to add more than one network.  For example in your poll service you need to have both "poll-tier" and "back-tier" so that the poll service can communicate with redis service.

Your compose file would look something like this:

```
version: '3.0'
services:
    poll:
        build: poll/.
        ports:
            - "5000:80"
        networks: 
            - poll-tier
    redis:
        image: "redis"
        expose: 
            - "6379"
        networks:
            - back-tier
            - poll-tier
    worker:
        build: worker/.
        networks: 
            - back-tier
    db:
        image: "postgres"
        volumes:
            - "db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data"
        networks:
            - back-tier
            - result-tier       
    result:
        build: result/.
        networks: 
            - result-tier
volumes:
    db-data:
networks:
    poll-tier:{}
    result-tier:{}
    back-tier:{}
```